# Simple question: Is there a pre-defined Japanese laptop keyboard layout for Ubuntu 18.04.3?

Tags: laptop, keyboard-layout, japanese

I've installed English Ubuntu 18.04.3 on the Japanese laptop **Panasonic Let's Note CF-LX6** (late 2016), and the keyboard layout is quite different from a European one. My lower row looks like this:

`<LCTL> <LWIN> <LALT> <MUHE> <SPCE> <HENK> <HKTG> <MENU> <RCTL>`

I also have no key between Left-shift and Z, but instead one additional key directly left of Right-shift, and one directly left of Back Space.

After installing, I added a Japanese keyboard in Input Method in Settings, but when checking the keyboard layout GUI, I see that the "Japanese" keyboard is a typical European keyboard with just slightly different symbols on it – the basic layout is still the same.

When checking in the keyboard layout GUI, I find that:
1)  My actual keys MUHE, HENK and HKTG, and the two extra keys mentioned above – the one directly left to Right-shift, and the one directly left to Back Space – do not respond to any key in either English or Japanese keyboard layout.
2) The keyboard layout keys SUPER_R and SUPER_L do not respond to any actual key on my keyboard. (i.e. they are unmapped)

I've checked with `XEV` that they unmapped keys do generate an event, with a keycode (but not all do –  for one thing, just zooms out all the windows and generates no keycode), so I do know that I can manually remap them in `XKB` (as in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077870/what-are-the-exact-steps-towards-remapping-the-japanese-keys-on-a-japanese-keybo) and other helpful ones), but it involves quite much (specifically as I need to disable the LWIN key function to get its keycode), and I would also like this to be recognized outside X, in which case `XKB` would not help.

My point is that this keyboard layout is not at all unusual – in fact, *it's very common on Japanese laptops*. I don't think I'm the first to install (English) Ubuntu on a Japanese laptop, so my question is whether I really need to do through all the hoops to re-map everything manually, or if there is a simple something I can do for Ubuntu to accept (hopefully outside of X) that my keyboard is a Japanese laptop keyboard layout? I found in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280590/need-help-using-a-japanese-keyboardnot-ime-in-ubuntu-12-10) an (impopular) response that I could reinstall and choose 'detect keyboard layout' on install. Is a re-install really the easiest choice?

Comment: You can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and then focus on keyboard model at first hand. There are a couple of Japanese options, but I have no idea if any of them is closer to your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find what keyboard it would be. Trying to find what type of keyboard the Let's Note has built-in, or if it's similar to any other.

Comment: There may be a need to request an [upstream](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config) update. Experienced Japanese users may know better how to deal with this, though.

Comment: Henkan - Muhenkan - Hiragana, These keys on the lower row are designed for the Word processor generation, some of the Windows 3.1 or earlier machines could work with the keys, since ATOK and MSIME got popular the manner of convert Hiragana into other characters, they got obsolete. But the design of JIS keyboard stays. And you can use them as the extra modifier keys.

Comment: Thanks, and I know that I can use them as other things. However, as I said, I don't think I'm the first to install Ubuntu on such a machine (there's GOT to be a lot of Japanese people using Ubuntu on their laptops), so I figured that there must be a setting where at least all of these buttons are mapped.  If there isn't, I can always do it manually, but I can't be the only one with such a keyboard.

Comment: Yes, some people set Hiragana-Katakana key for switching IME <> direct alphabet mode (instead of 'Ctrl/Super+space' by default), it's very handy for Japanese people must type English and Japanese quickly. Go to the Input Method Configuration window on Global Config tab, you see how. I'm using US keyboard (Japanese layout is not ideal to type for me.) If you prefer the US layout keyboard, I see someone selling it on the eBay or other parts sellers, it's not difficult to replace it.

Comment: @Sadaharu Wakisaka Replacing the keyboard itself, then? That doesn't exactly sound like a software solution :) The Input Method Configuration doesn't help me, my problem is that these keys arent' even mapped. Considering how common this keyboard layout is, there's got a be a pre-selectablabe set where these keys are mapped.

Comment: I just let you know about an alternate way of solving it. Gunnar already told you re-configuration of your keyboard,  open terminal and run the command, and select 'Generic 105-key (Intl)' or Fujitsu-Siemens laptop (looks like an OEM product of this company), but the configuration file itself sometimes is not well-written. You can try to find the difference by running a 'rescue-CD' or a BIOS hardware test.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the reconfiguration, but none of the ones I've tried have mapped anything to the <MUHE> or <HENK>. But I'll keep trying -- there are many to choose from, and I haven't tried them all. Thanks for the cuggestion of Fujitsu-Siemens laptop. I'll update here if I find anything.

Comment: I've googled images of the keyboards that seem interesting, and the closest match I've got is the "Sanwa Supply" keyboard included in the available pre-set keyboards in Ubuntu. It maps three of the missing keys - everything except <HENK> and <MUHE>. Strangely enough, though, the keyboard has two empty keys on those exact positions, but they don't respond to key presses. The keyboard layout has, however, no key for CTRL_R and SUPER_R. But the look of the keyboard is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first part - using the ibus-mozc sometimes the system (or you) confuses which layout to use.
 To make it right for Japanese keyboard layout.

```
sudo vi /usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml
```

And the edit the content of

```
<layout>default</layout>
```

into

```
<layout>jp</layout>
```

And also edit the file

```
sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard
```

And the content should be like:

```
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="jp"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Save them and reboot.

---

The second part using unused keys as modifier keys.

```
sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet
```

You get the lines at about 100th line.

```
key <HENK>   {      [ Henkan                ]       };
key <MUHE>   {      [ Muhenkan              ]       };
```

And change these, for example... Hyper_L and Meta_L

```
key <HENK>   {      [ Hyper_L                ]       };
key <MUHE>   {      [ Meta_L                 ]       };
```

Then your  and  keys will be assigned (when you reboot the computer.)

Comment: Thanks. That is the same solution I've seen elsewhere for remapping the keys HENK, MUHE and others, and it works. However, what I wondered was if there was a pre-selectable keyboard that represented this typical Japanese laptop layout, and the answer is -- no, there isn't. But I tinkered around a bit, and it's not that hard to make one, so I'll go ahead and do that. One thing I noticed is that there is no need to worry if some keys don't show up in the keyboard GUI (that you get if you select "show keyboard layout" in settings). The keys are still there and can be mapped.

Comment: Ubuntu has a Japanese team; https://www.ubuntulinux.jp they translate almost all the documents and make some useful tools for Japanese language (2-byte character problems), too. They suggest 'Generic 105 key; for a general Japanese keyboard. However the Japanese laptops have a very unique keyboard by makers, they have no time to catch up individual keyboard layouts. So Japanese users generally download a device driver from the maker, or it used to come a floppy or CD to install on Windows. For other OS we have to detect one by one. This is all I know.

Comment: Well, once I figure out the details, I can always make the layout for a Panasonic Let's Note. So at least that one can be done. It's just cosmetics, but it's still useful. I'll update when done. I don't know where to submit the finished file, but I guess I can figure that out too. Or ask ubuntulinux.jp.

Comment: Yes, you made it, very noble one. To submit the keyboard layout, we need a little concern at least it should be the integrated one for Let's Note. FYI, Let's note has 4 or more series and each one has a new product per year or 6 month, made in Kobe Japan. Their keyboards for one model are about 4 (JP, US, TH, TW) https://imgur.com/a/LRsUyHm (2 of 116 Let's note series, currently selling, there are thousands models in past) I am afraid the list of dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration filled with these and takes a very long time to scroll down, we need sub categories.

Comment: Don't worry, I can only make for one of them -- the one I have. I can always check to see if my keyboard is common to any other model. Though there are many models, I doubt that every single one has a unique keyboard. Didn't know that there are US keyboards for the Let's Notes, though. I was of the impression that these machines were only selling in Japan.